# Generate java content entities

Tags: java, hibernate, automation

I have a posgresql database managed with hibernate 4 and I want to know if there is a way to generate the java object entities coming from the content of the database.

If I have an hibernate object Test :

```
Test ( 
int id, 
String aString, 
String anotherString 
)
```

In the database I have in the table test :

```
ID,AString,AnotherString
1,uuuu,iiii
2,vvvv,xxxx
```

I'm looking for a method that generates a result like :

```
Test test1 = new Test(1,"uuuu","iiii");
Test test2 = new Test(2,"vvvv","xxxx");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible using hql,

For this what you have to do is

1) Create a constructor in your Test Class as

```
 public Test(int id,  String aString,  String anotherString ){
       this.id=id;
       this.aString=aString;
       this.anotherString =anotherString ;
```

}

2) While fetching data using hql write:
select new Test(entityAlias.id, entityAlias.aString , entityAlias.anotherString  ) from EntityName entityAlias;

In case of introspection 
1) Create a constructor where the order of arguments is the order od fields written in our class.

2) Manually prepare a query using reflection .

I have written a test program for query creation refer below:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<Test>  aClass = Test.class;
        Field[] fieldArray = null;
        String alias ="test";
        int length=0;
        try {
         fieldArray = aClass.getFields();
         length= fieldArray.length;
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        StringBuilder s=new StringBuilder("select new Test(");
        for(int index=0; index<length ;index++){
            s.append(alias+ "." +fieldArray[index].getName() );
            if( index != length -1){
                s.append(" , ");
            }
            else{
                s.append(" ) ");
            }
        }
        s.append(" FROM Test " + alias);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Output:
select new Test(test.id , test.aString , test.anotherString )  FROM Test test

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there a way to do this by introspection ?

Comment: Do you want to introspect the fields of Test Class first and then fetch the corresponding fields in your query?
If you liked the answer please upvote.

Comment: Yes. I'm looking for an automatic way to do this. Because in the solution proposed, i have to do manually the operation of query creation. Thanks